# Change dependency version number in pom.xml using scala-xml

Tags: scala, scala-xml

I want to use scala-xml to change the version number of one dependency in a bunch of pom.xml files. I know this is normally not the best way to approach such a task but in my use case I think it is.

Here is an example pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>theArtifactId</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I want to change the version of `hibernate-core` to `MY-SNAPSHOT`. This is my attempt to do this and I think it is close to a solution:

```
import scala.xml.transform.{RewriteRule, RuleTransformer}
import scala.xml.{Node, Elem, XML}

val newVersion = "MY-SNAPSHOT"

val rewriteRule = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(node: Node): Seq[Node] =
    node match {
      case e @ Elem(_, "dependency", _, _, _*) if (e \ "artifactId").text == "hibernate-core" => {
        val content = e.child.collect {
          case e @ Elem(_, "version", _, _, _*) => <version>{newVersion}</version>
          case e: Elem                          => e
        }
        <dependency>{content}</dependency>
      }
      case _ => node
    }
}

val pom = XML.loadFile("example-pom.xml")
val transform = new RuleTransformer(rewriteRule)
println(transform(pom).toString())
```

The problem is this somehow pulls the project attributes into the `groupId` and `artifactId` xml tags and duplicates them in the project tag, and it doesn't apply the correct formatting. How do I solve this?

I have seen various similar questions in this site but I'm not able to apply them to my problem.

EDIT: I simplified the transform method a bit and was able to fix the formatting but I do not understand how this attribute ends up in the wrong tags.

```
override def transform(node: Node): Seq[Node] =
    node match {
      case e: Elem if e.label == "dependency" && (e \ "artifactId").text == "hibernate-core" => {
        val content = e.child.map(child =>
          child.label match {
            case "version" => <version>{newVersion}</version>
            case _         => child
          }
        )
        <dependency>{content}</dependency>
      }
      case _ => node
    }
```